# Classe God x jQuery Mobile

Tags: metodologia, jquery-mobile

Sempre fui interessado em estudar sobre metodologias em relação a programação e ouvi muitos professores principalmente nas universidades falando mal das famosas classes Gods, que fazem tudo dentro dela. E agora me surgiu uma dúvida que considero interessante. Lendo alguns artigos sobre jQuery Mobile (tendo conhecimento que uma página html não é uma classe) que é muito incentivado a criar todas as suas telas separadas por `divs` o que dependedo pode deixar o seu arquivo imenso e pior se colocarmos nossos `js` juntos. Não seria mais correto fazer a divisão de telas jQuery Mobile por páginas html?

Answer (score 1):

## O problema com a analogia

A analogia entre uma classe com uma tela que usa estrutura HTML não pode ser feita de 1 para 1.

Ao dividir responsabilidades entre classes e métodos você tem um *overhead* de processamento e memória, mas é bem menor comparado a ter duas páginas em arquivos diferentes.

Além disso, a ideia de dividir responsabilidades envolve questões lógicas, acoplamento, manutenção e reuso.

No caso de uma estrutura HTML como proposta pelo jQuery Mobile, apesar de ser ruim trabalhar em um arquivo grande, não há efetivamente uma mistura entre as diversas seções.

O JavaScript poderia, sim, acabar misturando algumas coisas, mas nesse ponto vale a competência do programador de saber criar trechos específicos para cada tela.

Note que, mesmo com divisão de HTMLs em vários arquivos, ainda seria possível adicionar o mesmo script em todas as telas e haver confusão. Na verdade, esta é uma prática bem comum.

## Depende do contexto

A complexidade de um aplicativo e a sua respectiva otimização fazem com que não haja uma forma absolutamente "melhor" de juntar ou dividir responsabilidades.

Para evitar complexidade de desenvolvimento e manutenção o melhor seria dividir em vários HTMLs. Isso evitaria conflitos desnecessários durante os *merges* e simplifica a vida do desenvolvedor de várias formas. Também ocupa menos memória no dispositivo. Parece ser melhor para aplicativos que tem bastante conteúdo.

Já ter um HTML pode melhorar a experiência do usuário, pois a navegação entre as páginas será instantânea. Lógico que isso pode ter um efeito negativo caso o usuário queira ver apenas uma página. Esta parece ser a melhor solução para aplicativos relativamente pequenos, onde no geral a simplicidade fala mais alto.

## Considerações

O jQuery Mobile permite abordagens diferentes e mistas.

Na documentação sobre [*`pages`*](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.4/pages/), há informações de como fazer *single page template* (uma página por HTML) e *multi-page template* (várias páginas num HTML).

Ali também diz que usar essas estruturas são convenções, não uma obrigação. Há inclusive um tópico intitulado *Prefetching pages* que explica como pré-carregar várias páginas ao usar *single page templates*.

Uma solução mista mais vantajosa seria ter vários HTMLs, mas agrupar telas relacionadas em cada um.